# Apacheによる、Pythonコードの実行について

Tags: python, windows, apache

只今、『入門 Python3』を読みながら、JupyterLabを使ってPythonを学んでいます。OSはwindows10です。

この業界は初心者です。言葉や言葉の使い方が正確ではないことがあります。質問文で気になったことがあれば、何なりとご指摘くださいませ。私はそれを揚げ足取りとは感じません。自身の成長のために必要なことだと思っています。

『9.2.6.1 Apache』より本文を載せます。

> 次のテストファイルを作り、/var/www/test/home.wsgiとして保存しよう。
>
> ```
> import bottle
>
> appkication = bottle.default_app()
>
> @bottle.route('/')
> def home() :
> return "apache and wsgi, sitting in a tree"
> ```

1.これは、C直下のフォルダ、var/www/testにhome.wsgiというファイルを作るということでしょうか？

> apacheとmod_wsgiモジュールが正しく動作しているなら、あとはこれらをPythonスクリプトに接続するファイルに一行を追加する。
>   (中略)
>   デフォルトウェブサイトを指定するセクションに次の行を追加しよう。
>
> ```
> WSGISciptAlias / /var/www/test/home.wsgi
> ```

2.セクションにこの行を追加するというのは、apacheのhttpd.confのファイルにある `# Virtual hosts` のところにこの行を書き足すということでしょうか？

> すると、セクションは次のようになる。
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost　*:80>
> DocumentRoot /var/www
>
> WSGISciptAlias / /var/www/test/home.wsgi
>
> <Directory /var/www/test>
> Order allow,deny
> Allow from all
> </Directory>
> <VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> apacheを起動、または再起動して、この新しい設定を使わせよう。そして、http://localhost/ をブラウズすると、次のように表示されるはずだ。
>
> ```
> apache and wsgi, sitting in a tree
> ```

いろいろ試行錯誤しましたが、これは表示されませんでした。

そして、3つ目の質問ですが、mod_wsgiモジュールを使うために、`pip install mod_wsgi`とコマンドを実行しても、

```
Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

というエラーが出てうまくインストールできません。この解決方法を教えてください。

補足します。
Apacheは、[アパッチ 2.4 VS16 の Windows バイナリとモジュール](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/)にてダウンロードし、インストールしました。
また、初期設定は[Apache インストール （Windows編）](https://programming-style.com/apache/reference/install-win/)に従って行いました。

Comment: この記事あたりが参考になるかも。[Bottle、Flaskを使ってWebサーバを起動する(Apacheも使ってやってみた)](https://qiita.com/y518gaku/items/dbc41bf25d9ad0a5be60)

Comment: 根本的なところとして当該書籍はWindowsに対応しているのでしょうか？ まえがき等に書籍が想定する環境が記載されていないでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね。amazonにこんなレビューがありましたので参考になれば。[本書を Windows10 を使いながら学習予定の方へ](https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/customer-reviews/R1QM328N38U7AX/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=4873117380)

Comment: 参考にしている書籍はあくまで Python がメインであり、Apache の話題は軽く触れられている程度じゃないかと思われます。 / 質問の一つ目、二つ目は Apache をどのようにインストール・設定したかが分からないと詳しい回答が付けられないと思います。